# Does Realm DB Support Recursive Elements

Tags: android, realm

I know Realm DB does not support inheritance, but does it support Recursive class elements?  For example:

```
    public class FileItem{
          private String name;
          ArrayList<FileItem> elements;
    }
```

I am getting error

```
Type ArrayList<com.example.FileItem> elements is not supported ..
```

If I cannot do this I don't know how I can create levels for my file structures in a uniform way.  Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Realm does support recursive data structures, but please read this section on how to create Realm model classes: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models

In your case the model class should look like this:

```
public class FileItem extends RealmObject {
      private String name;
      private RealmList<FileItem> elements;
}
```